# What happens in degenerate case of multiple assignment?

Tags: python

I'm [teaching myself algorithms](http://rosalind.info/problems/list-view/?location=algorithmic-heights). I needed to swap two items in a list. Python makes all things easy:

```
def swap(A, i, j):
    A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
```

This works a treat:

```
>>> A = list(range(5))
>>> A
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> swap(A, 0, 1)
>>> A
[1, 0, 2, 3, 4]
```

Note the function is resilient to the degenerate case `i = j`. As you'd expect, it simply leaves the list unchanged:

```
>>> A = list(range(5))
>>> swap(A, 0, 0)
>>> A
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Later I wanted to permute three items in a list. I wrote a function to permute them in a 3-cycle:

```
def cycle(A, i, j, k):
    A[i], A[j], A[k] = A[j], A[k], A[i]
```

This worked well:

```
>>> A = list("tap")
>>> A
['t', 'a', 'p']
>>> cycle(A, 0, 1, 2)
>>> A
['a', 'p', 't']
```

However I (eventually) discovered it goes wrong in degenerate cases. I assumed a degenerate 3-cycle would be a swap. So it is when `i = j`, `cycle(i, i, k) ≡ swap(i, k)`:

```
>>> A = list(range(5))
>>> cycle(A, 0, 0, 1)
>>> A
[1, 0, 2, 3, 4]
```

But when `i = k` something else happens:

```
>>> A = list(range(5))
>>> sum(A)
10
>>> cycle(A, 1, 0, 1)
>>> A
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> sum(A)
11
```

What's going on? `sum` should be invariant under any permutation! Why does this case `i = k` degenerate differently?

How can I achieve what I want? That is a 3-cycle function that degenerates to a swap if only 2 indices are distinct `cycle(i, i, j) ≡ cycle(i, j, i) ≡ cycle(i, j, j) ≡ swap(i, j)`

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what behavior you're expecting out of the degeneration? Also note there's [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) that would shuffle the values - though you can't specify how it's going to shuffle them, only that it will eventually permute through all possible pairings. e.g. what about `cycle(A, 0, 0, 0)`?

Comment: @WayneWerner "a 3-cycle function that degenerates to a swap if only 2 indices are distinct" eg. `cycle(i, j, i) ≡ swap(i, j)`

Comment: I'm not sure that's well defined. That's enough to write a function for when `i=k`, but what if `j=k`? or `i=j`? Are those cases ignored?

Comment: Precisely: `cycle(i, i, j) ≡ cycle(i, j, i) ≡ cycle(i, j, j) ≡ swap(i, j)`. And of course `cycle(i, i, i)` should be the identity function.

Answer (score 23):

`cycle` is doing exactly what you ask it to: assigning to the left hand values the right hand values.

```
def cycle(A, i, j, k):
    A[i], A[j], A[k] = A[j], A[k], A[i]
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
def cycle(A, i, j, k):
    new_values = A[j], A[k], A[i]
    A[i], A[j], A[k] = new_values
```

So when you do `cycle(A, 1, 0, 1)` what you are saying is that you want

```
A[1] = previous_A[0]
A[0] = previous_A[1]
A[1] = previous_A[1]
```

If you want cycle to work sequentially then you must write it sequentially, otherwise python evaluates the right hand and then expands that to the arguments on the left hand.

Comment: Great explanation. It would be nice to also add an actual solution to the problem!

Comment: @DanielDarabos it would, if it was actually a problem.

Answer (score 11):

Well it seems *you are re-assigning to the same target* `A[1]`, to get a visualization of the call:

```
A[1], A[0], A[1] = A[0], A[1], A[1]
```

Remember, from the documentation on **[assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)**:

> An assignment statement *evaluates the expression list* (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and *assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.*

So your evaluation goes something like dis:

- Create tuple with values `A[0], A[1], A[1]` translating to `(0, 1, 1)`
- Assign these to the target list `A[1], A[0], A[1]` *from left to right.*

Assignment from left to right takes place:

1. `A[1] = 0`
2. `A[0] = 1`
3. `A[1] = 1`

So the first assignment made is `A[1]` with the first element of the tuple `0`, then the second assignment `A[0]` with the second element `1`  and, finally, at the end, `A[1]` *is overriden with the third element in the tuple* `1`.

---

You can get a more *convoluted* view of this with **[`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis)**; notice how all elements in the right hand of the assignment statement are loaded first and then they are assigned to their values:

```
dis.dis(cycle)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
              3 LOAD_FAST                2 (j)
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR
              7 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
             10 LOAD_FAST                3 (k)
             13 BINARY_SUBSCR
             14 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
             17 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             20 BINARY_SUBSCR                   # Loading Done
             21 ROT_THREE
             22 ROT_TWO
             23 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)  # Assign first
             26 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             29 STORE_SUBSCR
             30 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)  # Assign second
             33 LOAD_FAST                2 (j)
             36 STORE_SUBSCR
             37 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)  # Assing third
             40 LOAD_FAST                3 (k)
             43 STORE_SUBSCR
             44 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             47 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `cycle(A, 1, 0, 1)` becomes `A[1], A[0], A[1] = A[0], A[1], A[1]`, resulting in both `A[0]` and `A[1]` ending up with the old value of `A[1]`. `cycle(0, 0, 1)` works because it becomes `A[0], A[0], A[1] = A[0], A[1], A[0]`, which is equivalent to `swap(A, k, j)`.